# snmpwalk on a Cisco MIB imported in a Redhat server

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am experimenting with MIB files so forgive me if this sounds crazy. I wish to import a Cisco network device MIB file into a RHEL7 server having net-snmp and then use solarwinds snmpwalk to collect data.

I have imported the MIB from 'ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-RHINO-MIB.my' into the Redhat server but when I try to run a walk from the Redhat server itself, I get the following error -

```
[root@myLinuxServer ~]# snmptranslate -m +CISCO-RHINO-MIB -IR -On ciscoLS1010ChassisGroup

.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.5.11.1.1

[root@myLinuxServer ~]# snmpwalk -v 2c myLinuxServer -c privateall -m ALL ciscoLS1010ChassisGroup

CISCO-RHINO-MIB::ciscoLS1010ChassisGroup = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

[root@myLinuxServer ~]#
```

Here is the content of my snmpd.conf file:

```
####
# First, map the community name "public" into a "security name"

#       sec.name  source          community
com2sec notConfigUser  default       public
com2sec ConfigUser      default         privateconfig
com2sec AllUser         default         privateall

####
# Second, map the security name into a group name:

#       groupName      securityModel securityName
group   notConfigGroup  v1      notConfigUser
group   notConfigGroup  v2c     notConfigUser
group   ConfigGroup     v2c     ConfigUser
group   AllGroup        v2c     AllUser

####
# Third, create a view for us to let the group have rights to:

# Make at least  snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public system fast again.
#       name           incl/excl     subtree         mask(optional)
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
view    AllView       included   .1

####
# Finally, grant the group read-only access to the systemview view.

#       group          context sec.model sec.level prefix read   write  notif
access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none
access  ConfigGroup    ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none
access  AllGroup       ""      any       noauth    exact  AllView    none none

mibs +CISCO-RHINO-MIB
mibs +CISCO-SMI
```

I think that it is because my Redhat server does not have a 'LS1010 Chasis' in it (which must be present on the actual Cisco device), I get the 'No Such Object' message.

My question is, can we simulate such snmpwalk on a Cisco MIB by importing it into a Redhat server? If we can, any pointers on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Having a Cisco MIB does not mean that your server will 'pretend' it is a Cisco device.  the MIB only serves to describe the SNMP data hierarchy for the benefit of retrieving/viewing the data.  It converts the OID numbers into text.

If you'd like to monitor your Redhat server, you can snmpwalk the OIDs that are available and see what it offers, but I'd expect to see statistics on your CPU, memory, disk, and network devices.

See: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/snmp

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.Suppose I want to use the Cisco MIB as my custom MIB in Linux (saving myself from the hardwork of writing a custom MIB) and suppose I want to change the implementation code for the Cisco MIB, such that, 'ciscoLS1010ChassisGroup' should return all the active interfaces in the Linux server (vague example, I know the Linux MIB gives that already). Is there a way this can be done?